# Position words inside RTL div with both RTL & LTR languages and Numbers

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I have a `Right To Left` div, Inside I would like to have the following sentence (notice the words order):

[image: Desired Solution]

I'm unable to produce it.

So from **Right to Left**:

1. שלום1
2. English Words
3. 9000
4. עולם2

Html:

```html
    <div class="rtl_div">
      <p>
        שלום1 English Words 9000 עולם2
      </p>
      <p>
        <span class="position_1">שלום1</span>
        <span class="position_2">English Words</span>
        <span class="position_3">9000</span>
        <span class="position_4">עולם2</span>
      </p>
    </div>
```

css:

```css
.rtl_div{
  direction: rtl;  /* Must stay right to left */
 }
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pf8g2o6w/

Edit: following Tushar's answer I can solve it by changing the elements' display from `inline` to `block` but I would rather solve it by still keeping the elements as `display inline`:

`span { display: inline-block;}`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work
HTML

```
<div class="rtl_div">
  <p>
    שלום1 English Words 9000 עולם2
  </p>
  <div class="flexy">
    <span>שלום1</span>
    <span>English Words</span>
    <span>9000</span>
    <span>עולם2</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
<div style="direction: rtl">
  Expected: <br>
  <image src="https://i.imgur.com/Zj3NYHo.png"></image>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rtl_div{
  direction: rtl;  /* Must stay right to left */
}
.flexy{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  color: red;
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.flexy > span{
  margin-left: 3.5%;
}
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rz83e45s/5/

Comment: I still want to keep the element as inline, following your idea though, it would be easier just to use display inline-block, `span { display: inline-block;}`

Comment: When content of ````p```` tag is english ````rtl```` property justifies the content of p to left only and nothing else

When the content of ````p```` is not english it display the whole statement from right to left

In your case the first and last words are non english so their place is changed but the middle two are english letters and numbers so they are justified to left only